# My nMOSFET (maybe non existent). N canal with Vgs=0?

Tags: mosfet, nmos, education

if I realize the following nMOSFET:

[image]

is it possible to obtain n canal with \$V_{GS}=0\$?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi @Andy aka, what is wrong in my draw?

Comment: Have you heard of depletion mode FETs? N-Channel depletion mode FETs conduct when Vgs = 0. @Andyaka N-channel FETs have a P-body as their substrate, the gate voltage induces the N-channel.

Comment: Oh I see what he's asking now!!!

Comment: You can buy FETs with "floating gates" which are isolated by an insulating barrier. Charge is injected into this floating gate at manufacture so that Vgsth can be set at whatever voltage is desired - including 0 volts.